# ¿Cómo miro si una cadena contiene una cadena que tiene comillas VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net

Estoy usando `.contains` en un string para ver si contiene una cadena determinada.

Pero si esa cadena contiene `""` (comillas) me da error.

Por ejemplo:

```html
<tr><td width='30%'>God</td><td width="40%">
```

Me da error al tener la cadena doble comilla `""`.

Esto es lo que intenté:

```
Private searchString As String = "<tr><td width='30%'>God</td><td width=" + """ + "40%" +"""+">"
```

¿Cómo puedo hacerlo?

Comment: Simplemente escapa las comillas: `Private searchString As String = "<tr><td width='30%'>God</td><td width=\"40%\">"`

Comment: Private searchString As String = "<tr><td width='30%'>God</td><td width=\"40%\">" me da error de se esperaba fin de instrucción

Comment: Perdona, es que normalmente programo en C# no en vb.net. En vb la manera de escapar las comillas dobles es duplicandolas: `Private searchString As String = "<tr><td width='30%'>God</td><td width=""40%"">"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Utiliza el Comando Chr que muestra un Número de Carácter

```
Private searchString As String = "<tr><td width='30%'>God</td><td width="  + Chr(34) + "40%" + Chr(34) + ">"
```

Comment: Es mucho mejor escapar las comillas y no concatenar un string